# Iterate through array and return itself

Tags: crystal-lang

This code: `p [1, 2].each{ "foo" }` produces `nil`, whilst I want it to put `[1, 2]` after iteration. How-to in Crystal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`tap`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Object.html#tap%28%26block%29-instance-method):

```
p [1, 2].tap &.each { "foo" } # => [1, 2]
```

It yields self to the block and then returns self.

Another option **(not preferable)** could be creating a custom method that simply returns self after doing each:

```
class Array
  def each_with_self
    each { |x| yield x  }
    self
  end
end

p [1, 2].each_with_self { "foo" } # => [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case you are asking it could be enough to use parens in `p(..)` since `p` returns the argument as result.

```
p([1, 2]).each{ "foo" }
```

This behavior of `p` serves for doing easy inspections in the middle of an expression, i.e. changing `foo(bar, baz)` to `foo(p(bar), baz)`.

As for `#each`, in crystal it was decided to return `nil` to improve the generated code since the value is not used most of the time. This also prevents the generation of some unions at the end of the day.